# What is the best way to reset counter in database?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column in DB, where some details about searches performed by user are saved (searched data and timestamp). I have to implement a restriction, allowing to perform only 10 searches/day. Then the counter should reset at midnight.

Each time the request is made I need to check if there are already 10 searches saved in the DB (MSSQL). Then return 4xx response in controller if the limit is reached.

I was thinking about updating the searches list in DB every time the request is being made, and removing records with timestamp from last day. But I guess it is not the best solution from the performance point of view.

What would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: Do you need to keep an history of the searches or just the count for a single day? or a counter for a single user in a single day?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a count query?

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.user_id = ? and
      t.search_datetime >= convert(date, getdate())
```

With an index on `(user_id, user_datetime)`, this should be quite fast.

Otherwise, you need to write a trigger (or similar mechanism) to maintain a count, and to check that count for each possible search.